# Installing Biblatex

Tags: installing, linux

Disclaimer: I don't know which forum (Linux-manjaro or tex exchange )is suitable for this question, hence I am asking in both.

I installed Biblatex from CTAN. Now how do I install it. I am using texmaker. (There was a Readme file, but the proceduce mention didn't work for me, if you are interested in details let me know in the comment section).

Comment: Did you try `sudo pacman -S biber` as stated [in the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TeX_Live#Important_information)?

Comment: not sudo packman but I manually downloaded from Add/Remove Centre, but the it didn't yield any result. It showed bibla.sty missing error.

Comment: you should never need to get biblatex from ctan "by hand" your tex system package manager will install it and any dependencies. the linux system package manager if your tex came with the linux system or tlmgr for a "vanilla" texlive from tug.